# Calculate coordinates of circles covering a circle with double diameter

Tags: javascript, geometry, geospatial

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So given the gray circle center coordinates `x=a` and `x=b` and diameter `d`, what are the coordinates of the center of the other 6 circles with diameter `d/2`?

Note that the 6 circles plus the 7th circle in the middle, cover all the gray circle's area.

I'm trying to calculate this with JavaScript, I can probably port it from any other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a d/2 diameter circle in the center and it has a hexagon inscribed in it with the hexagon edges at the intersection of this circle with the outer d/2 circles.
For the outer d/2 circles, their center coordinates offsets are: 2 x distance from the main circle center to the hexagon side (in-radius), and considering the angle rotation.

EDIT:
sorry if to much math but should go like this:
small circle diameter is half circle diameter: d=D/2
hexagon side: s= d/2
hexagon in-radius : (d/2) * sqrt(3)/2
offset: (d/2)*sqrt(3)
so the coordinates are, considering center of large circle 0,0:
left: -(d/2)*sqrt(3), 0
left-up: -(d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos60, (d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos30
right-up: (d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos60, (d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos*30
right:+(d/2)*sqrt(3), 0
right-down: (d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos60, -(d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos*30
left-down: -(d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos60, -(d/2)*sqrt(3)*cos30

Comment: so how can I calculate that?

Comment: This almost works, but apparently the in-radius calculation is (d/2)*sqrt(3), so the offset would be d*sqrt(3). With that small change it worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given you have `6 cicles and 360 degree`, you can start at any point at the border of your gray circle (that would be the center of the first circle). and rotate this point each time with a `60°` each time to find the other circles centers.

Example.

- Gray circle center point is : `cx=0 & cy=0 with a ray R=2`
- Take a point at the border of your gray circle, `cx1=R && cy1=0` for
  example

now you have the first center point (R,0) from their you rotate this point 60° around the gray circle, so using rotation formula:

```
x' = x*cos(theta)-y*sin(theta)

y' = y*sin(tetha)+x*cos(theta)
```

the new point would be:

```
cx2 = cx1*cos(60) - cy1*sin(60) = R/2 = 1
cy2 = cy1*sin(60) + cx1*cos(60) = R/2 = 1
```

and so on untill you find all the centers `(cxk,cyk) where k in [1..6]`

Comment: Sorry I should mention that the 6 circles, plus the circle in the center, cover the whole area of the gray circle, so positioning the center of the first circle in the border wouldn't work